# How can i update my Python chart dynamically on flask?

Tags: python, flask, plotly

The following chart is static, but since i'll push data every second on my Flask app, i would like to know how to make it dynamic. I tried to search for example but the only ones i found were meant for Javascript, not Python.

Would it be possible to update this chart in real time with Python? Any advice?

```
 def index():

        rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=7500, freq='H')
        ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

        graphs = [

            dict(
                data=[
                    dict(
                        x=[1, 2, 3],
                        y= arr,
                        type='scatter'
                    ),
                ],
                layout=dict(
                    title='first graph'
                )
            ) 

        ]


        ids = ['graph-{}'.format(i) for i, _ in enumerate(graphs)]
        graphJSON = json.dumps(graphs, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

        return render_template('index.html',
                               ids=ids,
                               graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

Comment: Reload the page every second?

Comment: I can't reload the page every second, it would not be the best option for what i'm doing

Comment: You'll need some JS then. I don't know how your graph is rendered on the client, but if it's some kind of JS function with JSON data as input, you could periodically poll the server for changes and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: If you want the graph to be reloaded in real time, the best way is to use web sockets but this is more complex to implement and should come with a publish - subscribe mechanism. The other way is to use AJAX on the client side and make the client query the server on a regular basis (but you will have to send from the client information about what is already displayed in order to reduce the bandwidth use). However this is not only a Flask subject but a more general client / server topic. Finally this issue cannot be simply resolved by a server code.

Comment: @AlexC. what should i do in your opinion? Move and use a Javascript charting library?

Comment: @Jack022 It really depends your needs and the service you want to offer. If you are targeting financial services with many users connected at the same time, then go on with web sockets (but here the main question would be 'should you use Flask ?'). Otherwise, if you are writing a web service only for yourself, go on with AJAX.

Comment: @Alex well basically i'm already using websockets. From my Flask script i'm sending data via socket.io to my Javascript frontend. The problem now is charting this data. The problem is that if i put a chart on my Javascript frontend it won't show past data but the chart will start and reset each time the page is opened and closed, and see past data (before the page was opened) would not be possible. This is why i tried to print the chart straight from my backend, because it would have solved this problem i think

Comment: And by the way the final target should be a webapp used by more people

Comment: @Jack022 If you use web sockets already, write a publish - subscribe mechanism and send to your client the new data. Your client will have to maintain a state where it can hold the already acquired data. Then, a good way to avoid common issues is to have a single page app on the client side. Otherwise you can use cookies to maintain the data and allow the server and the client to know the amount of data already sent or received but this will increase the bandwidth use.

Comment: Got it. Maybe i should move to Dash, it could make everything easier

Answer (score 0):

Investigate Asynchronous JavaScript (AJAX).

`plotly` attempts to eliminate the need to write JavaScript. As a result, users often end up with nowhere to turn when they need simple JavaScript functions like periodic updating.

Comment: So basically it's impossible to update a chart on Python Plotly but it's possible on Plotly.Js?

Comment: Python Plotly uses Plotly.js under the hood to display your charts in your webpage. You don't need more/different `plotly` products, you need vanilla JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I'm using Plotly on my Python Flask script because if i use it on the backend my chart will have past data, while if i use a Javascript library the chart will reset each time the webpage gets opened and closed

Comment: I'm not aware of the specifics of your stack. Just know that extending `plotly` like you want requires JavaScript.